# Excel Pivot nest a column under some of my other columns problem

Tags: excel, nested, pivot, nest

I have this source of data cells:
[image]

I am trying to create a pivot nest the Model under the colors. Each color individually.
Haven't succeeded so far.
This is the result I'm aiming for:

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I think you will have a problem showing colors with an order total of zero, but not showing the models with an order total of zero when you expand the color row.  If you can accept NOT showing colors with order total of zero, then it can be done.

Comment: I can accept that. see edited wanted result please. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Power Query to pre-process the table:

- Select the first three columns
- Unpivot other columns
- Remove the values column
- Close and load as Pivot Table

Once you have the pivot table loaded

- Drag `Model` and `Attribute` to the Rows area
- Drag `Order Total` and `Order Amount` to the Values area

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table18"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(
        Source, 
        {"Model", "Order Total", "Order Amount"}, 
        "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Value"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

***Edit***

To use `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I have some experience in Excel but Power Query and let/in are not among the thing I used before. I'm trying to google everything you said

Comment: Ron the colors might change, I may come tomorrow and add 3 colors, is there a way to make the code more dynamic please?

Comment: @Kobe2424 What do you mean by "more dynamic"? If you mean adding a color and having everything automatically update, with no further action on your part, you will need to write a VBA event-triggered macro to update the query. That would warrant a separate question. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: I recorded the flow of what you said to a macro, and changed each field and variable that could be changed to work each time. for example the file name instead of write "file1.xlsx" I assigned a workbook variable. 
The "Let" and "In" you wrote above, the macro is writing in VBA each of the colors i have in the table, while the code you wrote doesn't mention the actual colors which is perfect.
My question is where do I put the "let" "in" code you wrote (M CODE)

Comment: @Kobe2424 I have edited my answer to add instructions for how to use Power Query.